# Where there is special Modulus in Microsoft Seal?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, lwe, ring-lwe

As explained in their example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/82b07db635132e297282649e2ab5908999089ad2/native/examples/3_levels.cpp#L59), Microsoft Seal uses a special modulus that is used for all key material like relinearization key. I wanted to ask why special modulus is used?

Comment: Found a concrete reason for that extra moduli , in appendix B of this paper they give overview of key-switching techniques https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1203.pdf  , basically they perform a modulus switch after key-switch to reduce the added noise. For this mod-switch they start with q'q and switch back to q (Ciphertext modulus). Same paper also talks about another decomposition based key-switching technique and Seal implements a hybrid approach using both techniques